# Block search SQL from happening

Tags: database, hooks, search, sql

I need to block some accesses to search *results* not the whole page, just the results.

The problem is, I need the search SQL query to not happen AT ALL. (I can conditionaly hide the output loop template very easily, I'm just not sure SQL is not happening).

Where would I prevent such thing (I assume some filter/action hook I just could not find the right one)?

**EDIT:** Please note, that the page needs to be loaded and displayed, otherwise I would proceed with request blocking approach like `template_redirect`

Comment: Can you please give some context on what is on the page that still needs to be displayed if you still need it to show and not redirect? it matters depending on what route you go.

Comment: @Elgoots basically everything else BUT not the results - instead of them, there should be an notice message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to avoid SQL execution in `WP_Query` with the `posts_pre_query` filter.

It's e.g. used by plugins to outsource the default search to 3rd party search engines.

Here's an example how we can override the main search query on the front-end, with an empty posts array and avoid running the SQL search query:

```
add_filter( 'posts_pre_query', function( $posts, \WP_Query $query ){
    if( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return array();
    }
    return $posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Since we're returning an empty array, I don't think we need to adjust the
`$query->found_posts` or `$query->max_num_pages` as they are zero by default.

Comment: This seems like the way, any ideas how would one differentiate between "nothing found" and "query blocked" (both empty posts array right?) ?

Comment: @jave.web You could `throw` a custom exception instead of returning the empty array and then `catch` that to differentiate.

Comment: @jave.web One way could be to set a custom query variable with the [set()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/set/) method if `WP_Query` within the `posts_pre_query` callback and then check it within the template with the [get()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get/) method.

Comment: @birgire that seems like a reasonable solution :)

Comment: `posts_pre_query` seems to be the one directly affecting if query is done or not, also interesting fact is that it is *not* affected by `'suppress_filters'` query settings unlike almost every other filter in `get_posts()` => ACCEPT. Sidenote: `pre_get_posts` is an action NOT a filter - you can set stuff there, but not filter the actual query :)